# Refreshing the RowFilter property on a DataView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, oledb, rowfilter

Here is what I am trying to do.  I have a form, with a 'filter' combobox and a DataGridView on it that displays the data from the database (I have assigned the data using the `DataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView` property.  The combobox has a list of items, found in the database, plus a custom added one (named ).  When the user selected one of the items, I the following code is run:

```
        int filterID = ( int )this.cbxFilter.SelectedValue;
        DataView view = this.dgvScenarios.DataSource as DataView;

        if ( filterID > 0 ) {
            view.RowFilter = string.Format( "Season = {0}", this.cbxFilter.SelectedValue );
        } else {
            view.RowFilter = string.Empty;
        }
```

Now, this works very well, as the `<All>` item is item 0.  Now, I can change the 'filtering' property, Season, on the form.  That has a similar combobox that has all of the same data in it as the 'filter' box, minus the `<All>` item.  When the user changes this value, this is what is run:

```
        if ( this._loading ) {
            return;
        }

        ComboBox cbx = sender as ComboBox;
        int rows = this.UpdateDataFromControl( cbx.Tag, cbx.SelectedValue );

        if ( rows <= 0 ) {
            return;
        }

        this.UpdateDGVCell( cbx.Tag, cbx.SelectedValue, "ID" );
        this.UpdateDGVCell( cbx.Tag, cbx.Text, "Text" );
```

Now, I would think that the DataView would update the data grid, but it does nothing, and I can't figure out how to do this refresh without loading the data into the dataset again, which would be a hit to performance as I am accessing the database, again, and then filtering it out.  Am I missing something that I haven't found on Google yet?  Thanks for any help, and if anymore information is needed, please let me know!

Comment: What do you mean by `Refreshing the RowFilter`?

Comment: When I change the 'Season' column in the DataSet, I am expecting the DataView to update and remove it from DataGridView because it is no longer a valid ID.  This is not, however, what happens.  The DataGridView is updated to show the new 'Season' value, but it isn't removed.

Comment: To reset the `RowFilter`, just set it to `string.Empty` looks like it's done somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you are using a DataView of the table, instead of using the table in a BindingSource? I have found the BindingSource easy to use.

Somewhere in your code you probably have something like this:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = yourDataSource;
```

If you replace that with

```
this.bindingSource = new BindingSource();
this.bindingSource.DataSource = yourDataSource;
dataGridView.DataSource = this.bindingSource;
```

Then you can apply filtering (with the event automatically triggered to update the DataGridView display) as follows:

```
this.bindingSource.Filter = "Season = 'x'"; //automatically updates the dataGridView
```

To remove the filter, you can use

```
this.bindingSource.RemoveFilter(); //automatically updates the dataGridView
```

Does this address what you are trying to do?